# How to resolve ambiguity in the definition of an LR(1) grammar?

Tags: parsing, go, ocaml

I am writing a Golang compiler in OCaml, and argument lists are causing me a bit of a headache.  In Go, you can group consecutive parameter names of the same type in the following way:

```
func f(a, b, c int)  ===  func f(a int, b int, c int)
```

You can also have a list of types, without parameter names:

```
func g(int, string, int)
```

The two styles cannot be mix-and-matched; either all parameters are named or none are.

My issue is that when the parser sees a comma, it doesn't know what to do.  In the first example, is `a` the name of a type or the name of a variable with more variables coming up?  The comma has a dual role and I am not sure how to fix this.

I am using the Menhir parser generator tool for OCaml.

Edit: at the moment, my Menhir grammar follows exactly the rules as specified at http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types

Comment: what does your grammar look like?

Comment: @tomwilde: I've edited the post with the proper information.  The code just follows the same structure as the specification.

Comment: I think the simplest approach is to treat any whitespace (without a comma) as a pre-type token. The token after the space (and there can only be one space without a comma) must be the type. If the token before the space doesn't match any type in the current scope, or any built in type, it must be a named variable.

This is probably overly naive.

Comment: `If the token before the space doesn't match any type` that would imply you have access to the current scope and the type names defined within it. That's a bad idea. C does it. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, the go grammar is not `LALR(1)`. In fact, it is not `LR(k)` for any `k`. It is, however, unambiguous, so you could successfully parse it with a `GLR` parser, if you can find one (I'm pretty sure that there are several GLR parser generators for OCAML, but I don't know enough about any of them to recommend one).

If you don't want to (or can't) use a `GLR` parser, you can do it the same way Russ Cox did in the `gccgo` compiler, which uses `bison`. (`bison` can generate GLR parsers, but Cox doesn't use that feature.) His technique does not rely on the scanner distinguishing between type-names and non-type-names.

Rather, it just accepts parameter lists whose elements are either `name_or_type` or `name name_or_type` (actually, there are more possibilities than that, because of the `...` syntax, but it doesn't change the general principle.) That's simple, unambiguous and `LALR(1)`, but it is overly-accepting -- it will accept `func foo(a, b int, c)`, for example -- and it does not produce the correct abstract syntax tree because it doesn't attach the type to the list of parameters being declared.

What that means is that once the argument list is fully parsed and is about to be inserted into the AST attached to some function declaration (for example), a semantic scan is performed to fix it up and, if necessary, produce an error message. That scan is done right-to-left over the list of declaration elements, so that the specified type can be propagated to the left.

It's worth noting that the grammar in the reference manual is also overly-accepting, because it does not express the constraint that "either all parameters are named or none are". That constraint *could* be expressed in an LR(1) grammar -- I'll leave that as an exercise for readers -- but the resulting grammar would be a lot more difficult to understand.

Comment: `gccgo` is maintained by Ian Lance Taylor, not Russ Cox. Tomita's GLR can parse highly ambiguous grammars. It has a worst time complexity of O(n³). It has trouble with right-nullable rules such as IdentifierList. [The Go grammar is, in fact LALR(1)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/jVjbH2-emMQ/UdZlSNhd3DwJ).

Comment: @tomwilde: In the post you linked, Russ says exactly the same thing as I do: "If you approach it that way, then it needs unlimited lookahead, even in an LALR(1) grammar, because you don't know until you have parsed an arbitrary amount of extra stuff how to reduce the 'a'." He goes on to sketch the same solution I sketch in my answer. That's not surprising, since I wrote the answer after looking at `go.y` in the `gccgo` source. By the way, GLR can be parsers are O(n) if the grammar is unambiguous, and the right nullability problem, while annoying, has a known solution implemented in bison.

Comment: That just means that OP is approaching the problem the wrong way. I don't see Russ Cox suggesting anybody to use GLR, which was designed for natural language processing.

Comment: @rici: thank you, it's pretty much was I was considering doing, however I wanted to make sure I was not missing a subtlety that would make it parseable directly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have ambiguity. The fact that the standard Go parser is LALR(1) proves that.

> is a the name of a type or the name of a variable with more variables coming up?

So basically your grammar and the parser as a whole should be completely disconnected from the symbol table; don't be C – your grammar is not ambiguous therefore you can check the type name later in the AST.

These are the relevant rules (from http://golang.org/ref/spec); they are already correct.

```
Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .
```

I'll explain them to you:

```
IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .
```

The curly braces represent the kleene-closure (In POSIX regular expression notation it's the asterisk). This rule says "an identifier name, optionally followed by a literal comma and an identifier, optionally followed by a literal comma and an identifier, etc…  ad infinitum"

```
ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
```

The square brackets are nullability; this means that that part may or may not be present. (In POSIX regular expression notation it's the question mark). So you have "Maybe an IdentifierList, followed by maybe an ellipsis, followed by a type.

```
ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
```

You can have several ParameterDecl in a list like e.g. `func x(a, b int, c, d string)`.

```
Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
```

This rules defines that a ParameterList is optional and to be surrounded by parenthesis and may include an optional final comma literal, useful when you write something like:

```
func x(
    a, b int,
    c, d string, // <- note the final comma
)
```

The Go grammar is portable and can be parsed by any bottom-up parser with one token of lookahead.

---

Edit regarding *"don't be C"*: I said this because C [is context-sensitive](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124570/why-pointer-symbol-and-multiplication-sign-are-same-in-c-c) and the way they solve this problem in many (all?) compilers is by wiring the symbol table to the lexer and lexing tokens differently depending on if they are defined as type names or variables. This is a hack and should not be done for unambiguous grammars!

Comment: > These are the relevant rules (from http://golang.org/ref/spec); they are already correct.

They aren't, otherwise inputting them into an LR(1) parser generator would not yield a shift/reduce conflict.  When the parser sees an identifier, is it looking at a variable name or type name?  It doesn't know and can't decide whether to shift or reduce.  Right now my idea is to just do a more dumb parsing and pick out variables and types in a post-processing step.

Comment: The grammar is unambiguous but it's not LR(1) as written. Suppose we've read `func g(a` and the lookahead token is `,`. The `identifier` `a` could be reduced to a `Type` or to an `IdentifierList`. That will be resolved once you reach either a `)` or an identifier followed by `...` or something which could start a `Type` (like another identifier), but that resolution could be any number of tokens ahead of the parse, which means that the grammar isn't `LR(k)` for any `k`.

Comment: I don't think you understand how a push-down automaton works. 1 token of lookahead does not mean that the parser will reduce after every shifted token. [You are wrong.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/jVjbH2-emMQ/UdZlSNhd3DwJ)